# Components using Date objects produce different snapshots in different timezones

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm using [Enzyme](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/) with [enzyme-to-json](https://github.com/adriantoine/enzyme-to-json) to do [Jest](https://facebook.github.io/jest/) snapshot testing of my React components. I'm testing shallow snapshots of a `DateRange` component that renders a display field with the current range (e.g. `5/20/2016 - 7/18/2016`) and two `DateInput` components that allow selecting a `Date` value. This means that my snapshot contains the `Date`s I pass to the component both in the `DateInput` props and in a text representation it resolves itself. In my test I'm creating some fixed dates using `new Date(1995, 4, 23)`.

**When I run my test in different timezones, this produces different snapshots**, because the `Date(year, month, ...)` constructor creates the date in the local timezone. E.g. use of `new Date()` produces this difference in snapshot between runs in my local timezone and on our CI server.

```
- value={1995-05-22T22:00:00.000Z}
+ value={1995-05-23T00:00:00.000Z}
```

I tried removing the timezone offset from the dates, but then the snapshot differed in the display field value, where the local timezone-dependent representation is used.

```
- value={5/20/2016 - 7/18/2016}
+ value={5/19/2016 - 7/17/2016}
```

**How can I make my tests produce the same `Date`s in snapshots regardless of the timezone they're run in?**

Answer (score 83, accepted):

I struggled with this for hours/days and only this worked for me:

1) In your test:

```
Date.now = jest.fn(() => new Date(Date.UTC(2017, 7, 9, 8)).valueOf())
```

2) Then change the `TZ` env var before running your tests.
So the script in my package.json:

- (**Mac & Linux only**)

  ```
  "test": "TZ=America/New_York react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
  ```
- (**Windows**)

  ```
  "test": "set TZ=America/New_York && react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
  ```

Comment: This (IMO) should be the accepted answer. Specifically, step #2 was sufficient for me. I just added a quick `TZ` environment variable in my test script declaration, and it worked like a charm. I didn't even have to mock out any Date function.

Comment: Cool, I'll mark it as accepted then. As it got posted almost a year after my original troubles, I never saw it till now :)

Comment: Here's the whole line I'm now using `"test": "TZ=America/New_York jest",`. That's all it took. Thank you!

Comment: Specifying `TZ=...` also worked for me! For reference http://www.timezoneconverter.com/cgi-bin/tzc has a list of timezone values that should all work.

Comment: I get the error 'TZ is not recognized as an internal or external command,'. Do I have to install something ?

Comment: Ok I figured it out and edited the answer with the solution.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this more.  Wasted an entire day on this issue before finding this post.  For context I used it as part of a Jenkins pipeline
`"CI=true TZ=America/Los_Angeles npm test"`

Comment: I get : "react-scripts" is not found :( I tried "test": "set TZ=UTC jest". But this didn't work either.

Comment: You save my day ! 
@Devid  For all env (install cross-env package before) :
`"test": "cross-env TZ=America/New_York && react-scripts test --env=jsdom"`

Answer (score 6):

I ended up with a solution comprised of two parts.

1. Never create `Date` objects in tests in timezone-dependent manner. If you don't want to use timestamps directly to have readable test code, use `Date.UTC`, e.g.

   ```
   new Date(Date.UTC(1995, 4, 23))
   ```
2. Mock the date formatter used to turn `Date`s into display values, so that it returns a timezone-independent representation, e.g. use `Date::toISOString()`. *Fortunately this was easy in my case, as I just needed to mock the `formatDate` function in my localization module. It might be harder if the component is somehow turning `Date`s into strings on its own.*

---

*Before I arrived at the above solution, I tried to somehow change how the snapshots are created. It was ugly, because enzyme-to-json saves a local copy of `toISOString()`, so I had to use `_.cloneDeepWith` and modify all the `Date`s. It didn't work out for me anyway, because my tests also contained cases of `Date` creation from timestamps (the component is quite a bit more complicated than I described above) and interactions between those and the dates I was creating in the tests explicitly. So I first had to make sure all my date definitions were referring to the same timezone and the rest followed.*

---

*Update (11/3/2017): When I checked `enzyme-to-json` recently, I haven't been able to find the local saving of `toISOString()`, so maybe that's no longer an issue and it could be mocked. I haven't been able to find it in history either though, so maybe I just incorrectly noted which library did it. Test at your own peril :)*

Answer (score 5):

I did this by using `timezone-mock`, it internally replaces the global `Date` object and it's the easiest solution I could find.

The package supports a few test timezones.

```
import timezoneMock from 'timezone-mock';

describe('when in PT timezone', () => {
  beforeAll(() => {
    timezoneMock.register('US/Pacific');
  });

  afterAll(() => {
    timezoneMock.unregister();
  });

  // ...
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/timezone-mock

Answer (score 1):

I ended up getting around this by mocking the `toLocaleString` (or whatever toString method you are using) prototype.  Using `sinon` I did:

```
var toLocaleString;

beforeAll(() => {
    toLocaleString = sinon.stub(Date.prototype, 'toLocaleString', () => 'fake time')
})

afterAll(() => {
    toLocaleString.restore()
})
```

This way if you are generating strings straight from a `Date` object, you're still OK.

Comment: Unfortunately, as I describe in my answer, `enzyme-to-json` saves and uses a local copy of `Date.toISOString`, so the stub doesn't affect the result.

Comment: @morgs32 At the time of writing, I distinctly remember looking at code doing just that. But now I can't find it anywhere, so I can't be sure that it wasn't in some library used as dependency or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

2020 solution that works for me

```
beforeEach(() => {
        jest.useFakeTimers('modern');
        jest.setSystemTime(Date.parse(FIXED_SYSTEM_TIME));
});

afterEach(() => {
        jest.useRealTimers();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `new Date()` constructor instead of Date.now you can do like below:

```
const RealDate = Date;

beforeEach(() => {
  // @ts-ignore
  global.Date = class extends RealDate {
    constructor() {
      super();
      return new RealDate("2016");
    }
  };
})
afterEach(() => {
  global.Date = RealDate;
});
```

[This issue](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2234) is a must visit if you're here.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `TZ=UTC` to my `.env` file solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

A simple fact can make it easy.

Just use :

```
new Date('some string').
```

This will always give an invalid date and no matter which machine, it will always be invalid date.

cheers.