# React JS : How to set default timezone for application

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-redux

I am writing End to End test cases for my React based UI application. Everything looks good and runs as expected except the date assertion is failing on my local machine while it passes on my CI server.

I figured out that the issue is the timezone picked up by the application is the OS time zone. I want to set this timezone to `UTC` by default.

FYI, I am also using moment library but I want to achieve this at redux level i.e. inside a configuration file I put something like `default.timezone=UTC` and it starts converting dates to UTC by default.

Comment: Question similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40935886/components-using-date-objects-produce-different-snapshots-in-different-timezones

Comment: No it's not I want to set default timezone to be picked by my application in general via some standard config.

Comment: try with moment js