# How to handle timezones in Cypress snapshot tests?

Tags: javascript, date, time, jestjs, cypress

We use Cypress and `cypress-image-snapshot` for snapshot testing. Unfortunately we have issues with our colleagues based in another countries running the tests since they fail because of different timezones.
In our date related components we pass strings in ISO 8601 format to set the date.

For our jest tests we use mocks ([Components using Date objects produce different snapshots in different timezones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40935886/components-using-date-objects-produce-different-snapshots-in-different-timezones)) but not quite sure how to handle the situation in Cypress.

Comment: The Cypress [docs](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/visual-testing.html) specifically highlight `cy.clock`, have you looked into that?

Comment: `cy.clock()` is for speeding up JS timer functions like `setTimeout()`, nothing to do with timezones so you can ignore that approach.

Comment: You should be able to manage timezone issues by structuring the test so that it only checks **relative** time values. Could you please post a simple example to illustrate the problem?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can open browser with different TZ from server by adding specific timezone before open, in this way

```
"scripts": {
  "cypress:open": "TZ=America/New_York cypress open",
  "cypress:run": "TZ=America/New_York cypress run"
}
```

Comment: yep, this is eventually what I did as there is no dedicated api by cypress

Comment: This doesn't work for Windows. I know i have to use " SET TZ=America/New_York cypress run" but it wont work

Comment: worked for me on my terminal but not in gitlab ci :/ thx anyways its useful